# jQuery bxSlider plugin, slideReloader not reloading at all

Tags: javascript, jquery, bxslider

I am using the JQuery bxSlider plugin to show images that are in a directory. The plan is that at the end of each cycle, the directory is re-read, and the list of images on the page is reloaded so there's a constant update of images being displayed.

The list of images that is loaded works, as the PHP file that is called by the `load` function is included on initial page load by PHP `include`, and when `load` is called, the HTML is updated correctly.

The first cycle of images works fine, but when it comes to the time to reload the relevant slider, it just goes back to the first image and stops; when the browser window is changed (eg, size) the image completely disappears.

So the issue is somewhere in where I'm calling `images.reloadSlider` - and I know it's something to do with how I've called it, but not sure where I've gone wrong...

My code is thus: (Updated to show HTML as well as minor change from suggested comment)

```
<body style='background: black; overflow: hidden; margin: 0;'>
 <div id="container">
  <div class="slider">
    <div style="background:black;"><img src="./20170725_193824.jpg"/></div>
    <div style="background:black;"><img src="./20170815_140415.jpg"/></div>

    <!-- ... etc... -->

  </div>
 </div>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
      var images = $('.slider').bxSlider({
        mode: 'fade',
        auto: true,
        controls: false,
        pager: false,
        pause: 8000,
        speed: 1000,
        onSlideBefore: function($slideElement, oldIndex, newIndex) {
          if (newIndex == 0) {
            $("#container").load("piclist.php");
            images.reloadSlider();
          }
        }
      });
    });
  </script>

</body>
```

I have also tried to put a `destroySlider()` call in there, both before and after I've called `load`, but the same thing happens.

I'm not brilliant with JS to be honest, though do have a fairly good knowledge of PHP (not that PHP is relevant here, except to say that I do know code!) - this is kind of a learning exercise for me! (But rest assured it's not me asking you to do my homework for me!)

Comment: It looks like your JS/jQ is ok...except this line;

Comment: (...continued) `$("#slider").load("piclist.php");` I don't know enough PHP to say what's wrong or what's right. To be nit picky your should use `===` rather than `==`. Just noticed a possible big mistake. There's `$('.slider')` and then at the end `$('#slider')`. I'm not 100% sure there's no HTML posted.

Comment: Yeah, realised that might have been noticed! The `div` in question has `slider` as both its class and its id. (Again, that was something I checked!) The contents are being correctly loaded from the file; when the page loads it loads in the right place with an `include()` PHP call and hasn't been altered. I've just tried adding a container div, around the slider div, but still got the same problem. Thanks for your help though!

Comment: Original post amended with updated (and fuller) code

Comment: Try using "===" instead of  "==" they have different behavior. The include is a `<div class='slider'>` with different images?

Comment: The `==` has been changed to an `===` with no (noticeable) effect. In that 'if' statement, the `$("#container").load("piclist.php");` line runs, but the `images.reloadSlider();` line doesn't. Originally, piclist.php was everything within `<div class='slider'>` but now is everything within `<div class='container'>`. I have a feeling this isn't necessarily an issue with my Javascript, but one with bxSlider... Appreciate the help though!

Comment: If you want to run the images in `.container` you have to instantiate bxSlider on that particular div. `var bx = $('.container').bxSlider({...` The original `var images = $('.slider').bxSlider({...` will break if you place a large element under the same ancestor.

Comment: The content of `piclist.php` is sibling to `.slider` it doesn't replace the `.slider`.

Comment: The `load` _does_ replace all the contents of the `.container` div though, which includes the whole `.slider` div. My original code (which still didn't work) didn't have the container div, and replaced the _contents_ of the slider div (but not the div itself). Changing it to `$("#container").bxSlider({...` stops the slider from working and just shows all the images one after the other as I manually scroll down the page.

Comment: If the `$('.slider')` is overwritten, then there's nothing for bxSlider to reload.

Comment: Just verify, you want this `piclist.php` to replace `.slider` when it goes back to the first slide, correct?

Comment: It's to replace the _inside_ of `.slider` not the div itself (I've reverted to take the `.container` div away again now as it didn't make a difference). `<div class="slider"> <div><img src="1.jpg"/></div><div><img src="2.jpg"/></div> </div>` is the basic code - the two inside divs containing the images changes, but the main `<div class="slider">` remains the same, and _is the same as it is when the page is loaded_. There is no issue with `('.slider').load("piclist.php")`; the contents of that div loads as expected. It's just the `images.reloadSlider();` bit of the code that isn't.